# How can I make the website I'm working on load faster?

Tags: php, performance, load

I am working on a website that I "inherited" in my job and it currently uses PHP/HTML/CSS/JS and it takes AGES to load, but the thing is without the PHP it loads really fast. I, however, am not very experienced with PHP so I don't know exactly where should I tweak it for it to work faster. First at the very top of the page I have this code to preload everything:

```
<?

?>
```

Then further down a table gets made using this code (which I know I can get better just don't know how exactly since tables on the db seem to be unrelated and they specifically asked me not to touch the db.

```
<?
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($domains as $row){
            $count++;
    ?>
```

a little of html goes here in between (mostly rows of a table) and then:

```
<? 
     } ?>
```

So after about 2 days messing with the site I know my html/css/js is optimized but the php keeps making me wait around 5 - 10 seconds for everything to load (sometimes even longer) which of course is unacceptable, could anybody please help me out here?

**EDIT**

I tried taking some of the connections outside from the foreach loop but I get an error if I do so =/

Comment: Did you measure the contribution of the database to those 5-10 seconds?  I can't believe this code would run for 5-10 seconds straight so I believe you're waiting for the DB, and that's where you'll have to start looking for improvements.

Comment: In my opinion `$contentdb = new wpdb("$user", "$pass", "$db", "$ip");` should be before **foreach** statement, NOT inside **foreach**.

Comment: other question, does the server already use an opcode cache like Zend, APC or eAccelerator?

Comment: @fvu I do not know if the server already uses those, let me check and get back to you

Comment: the server doesn't have Zend APC or eAccelerator

Answer (score 3):

Use a profiler like [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/xhprof) or [xdebug](http://pecl.php.net/xdebug)+kcachegrind to find the places of your code that take a long time (or are executed too often) and optimize them.

Answer (score 1):

First you should start by stopping writing queries in the `foreach` loop.

Get rid of queries which use `LIKE` statements.

Then you should recheck the indexes for the given tables. Rule of thumb would be that all rows which appear in `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses should be indexed ( well .. there are exceptions , but you should be able to figure on case-to-case base ).

And you could get rid of the `switch` statement and replace it with array lookup.

.. well .. my 2 cents.

Comment: question if I get rid of the "LIKE" statements what can I use instead with the same effect? Would that be what you mentioned of checking all rows that appear in WHERE and GROUP  BY? Also, to get rid of the queries in the foreach loops would it be enough if I make an array that contains all the values? or what would you suggest?

Comment: The first step would be to replace it with `MATCH .. AGAINST` and actually examine what sort of lookup that is ( maybe you can mimic effect with simple `VARCHAR` column .. or maybe they are comma separated values ). As for `WHERE/GROUP BY` clauses , i meant that you should make sure that rows which are used in them are indexed in one form or another.

Comment: ok let me start checking that, a question though, when I take the connections ( $contentdb = new wpdb("$user", "$pass", "$db", "$ip");) from the foreach loop (that is, I put them outside of it) I get errors saying the connection isn't available. Why is this happening?

Comment: Check how many items there are in `$domains`. If it is empty, then the connection might not be initiates.